# Select input field according to TH and TR

Tags: xpath

I have a next table with TH:

```
<table cellspacing="1" border="1" id="FinancialsGrid">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Slice</th>
            <th>Units</th>
            <th>Accrual Rate</th>
            <th>Trend Factor</th>
            <th>Base Units</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="3">Lorem Ipsum</td>
            <td>Previous</td>
            <td>6,866</td>
            <td>0.00 %</td>
            <td>0.00 %</td>
            <td>6,866</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Current</td>
            <td>6,866</td>
            <td>0.00 %</td>
            <td>0.00 %</td>
            <td>6,866</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Proposed</td>
            <td>6,866</td>
            <td><input type="text" style="width:60px;" value="0.00 %"></td>
            <td style="width:60px;"><input type="text" style="width:60px;" value="0.00 %"></td>
            <td style="width:60px;"><input type="text" style="width:90px;" value="6,866"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I need to select an xpath for input field according to e.g. "Trend Factor" column.

My variant which I wrote doesn't work:

```
//table[@id='FinancialsGrid']/tbody/tr/td/input[count(//table/thead/tr/th[.='Trend Factor'])]
```

Table view:
[image]

Comment: first of all, it looks like you have 6 columns in your head, and 5 columns in the last two rows.

Comment: yeah, that is right. I provided correct variant as is. Lorem Ipsum is like a general.

Comment: column/row number, which one can be fix and which one can be change? if number of rows are fix, you need to go to N:th <tr> element

Comment: I provided table structure as is. It can't be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the XPath

```
(//table[@id='FinancialsGrid']//input)[count(//tr/th)-index-of(//tr/th, //tr/th[text()='Trend Factor']) + 1]
```

or another one without **index-of()** function (for Firebug):

```
(//table[@id='FinancialsGrid']//input)[count(//tr/th)-count(//tr/th[text()='Trend Factor']/preceding-sibling::*)]
```

Will grab required input node, where:

```
count(//tr/th) is count of columns
index-of(//tr/th, //tr/th[text()='Trend Factor']) - current number of column
(//table[@id='FinancialsGrid']//input) - sequence of input nodes.
```

So we calculating position of input node and grubbing node from sequence.
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, structure can't be changed. This is as designed. Need to create xpath for input according to current table structure.

Comment: @dan-silver, yep, missed attribute *rowspan=3* - updated XPath for your table.

Comment: Displays invalid Xpath in firebug

Comment: Firebug doesn't know XPath function **index-of()** - just workaround it with simple **count()** function

Comment: Works but, input from another column (th) was located.

Comment: XPath selects input under **Trend Factor** column, attached screenshot with result, may be you missed difference with **+1** in first and second XPaths.

Comment: Oh, made a mistake in comment. I forgot to specify that if I will specify another column name (e.g. Accrual Rate) then input from last colmn will be selected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90343/discussion-between-den-silver-and-crowell).